# deleting list element if the element is present on another column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a list of dataframe `list=[df1,df2,df3,df4,...df10]`  the dataframe are constructed as following :

```
>df1
     col1  col2  col3  col4
      Y     2     XX     PP
```

I have another dataframe `DATA_SEL` such that

```
>DATA_SEL
col1  col2  col3  col4
A      KK   C      D
A1     PP   C      D
...................
..................
```

If the first value (a string) of `col4` for every dataframe in `list` (`df1 ,df2,df3....df10` )does not match with any value of `col2` in `DATA_SEL` , I want to delete that `df` from `list`.
How could I possibly do that?

Also if I want to construct a new list, `list2` where the first value (a string) of `col4` for every dataframe in `list` (`df1 ,df2,df3....df10` ) matches with any value of `col2` in `DATA_SEL` , how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with filtering:

```
L = [df1,df2,df3,df4,...df10]

#tested first value of col4
out = [x for x in L if DATA_SEL['col2'].eq(x.at[x.index[0], 'col4']).any()]
#if first row has index == 0
out = [x for x in L if DATA_SEL['col2'].eq(x.at[0, 'col4']).any()]

#tested any value of col4
out = [x for x in L if DATA_SEL['col2'].isin(x['col4']).any()]
```

Comment: Thanks very much .That worked like magic. I was using for loop which was getting complicated.

Comment: @Jewel_R - Sorry, I change solution for test first value, first solution test any value of `col4`